# Another phrase for "we recall that"

Tags: phrases, expressions

I am writing a thesis and frequently I have to use the phrase "we recall that....".
Is there any other phrase to use for better writing? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Hello, monalisa; you sound as if you could be a valuable member here. But your question could well be put on hold as it's not graced by reasonable evidence of research. Have you looked up 'recall' in a thesaurus for synonyms? Is any of these a reasonable substitute for 'recall'? Yes, you won't find many idiomatic multiword expressions (eg 'as we have seen', 'as discussed above', 'as shown in section 7', this way, but you _will_ have shown reasonable evidence of trying.

Comment: When you need to use 'we recall that...' in your thesis are you referring to points raised or arguments made earlier in the thesis or are you referring to external, possibly historical, events or facts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the phrase to point to an earlier comment in your thesis then it's common to use 'see above' or 'as stated above', possibly with a paragraph counter or heading reference.

If you're using the phrase to point to a fact or theory from another work there a bunch of phrases that use the other author / source eg 'as stated by...'

If you're using the phrase to refer to a collective memory, you could use a bunch of synonyms for recall that are more colloquial or archaic eg 'if we harken back to...', 'mind that...', 'call back to'.

The other alternative is to restructure your thesis so that you lay out and name any facts or theories that you're referring to at the beginning of the thesis / chapter / section and refer to these by name - 'Blamo Theory says that...' or 'Database A gives us...'. Whilst time consuming to write, this is a common way of writing in many fields of academia. Doesn't necessarily make easy reading though